# web api (asp.net) - sending data via post method

Tags: asp.net, rest, post, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to pass data via post method from my client to a server.

I'm using WebApi to do so.

This i the code i used:

client:

```
var client = new RestClient();
client.EndPoint = @"http://localhost:57363/hello";
client.Method = HttpVerb.POST;
client.PostData = "{value: Hello}";
var json = client.MakeRequest();
Console.WriteLine(json);
Console.Read();
```

server:

```
// POST api/<controller>
public string Post([FromBody]string value)
{
    return value + ", world.";
}
```

The server responds as expected when using postman. However, the client passes a null value instead of the real value.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: not sure that's the actual error, but maybe the Hello should be `"hello"`

Comment: btw are you sure that the request is getting to the server? cause few things seems broken here `@"http://localhost:57363/hello";` should be `@"http://localhost:57363/Post";`. you should use `[HttpPost] `data-annotation above the Post action. and the value is not as string either..

Comment: Thank you Liran. Actually I tried several options, including "hello", but non worked. The funny thing is that using "Postman" - it works as expected, with the endpoint as it appears in the code.  so I assume that the server side is written correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First of all a correct json would look like "{value: 'Hello'}".
I use [json-online](http://json.parser.online.fr/) to easily validate such inline json.

On the other hand, I think that you should send just the value in this case, not the entire json (because you are trying to resolve a simple type,a string), so the client should send a request like:

```
client.PostData = "'Hello'";
```

Comment: Thank you bandreas. It Worked!